# SeekBar width in a TableRow?

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-tablelayout

I need to create a control to make it easier to develope some screens at work.
The control is quite simple, just two buttons and a SeekBar. The buttons just used to increase or decrease the SeekBar value.

Here is my code:

```
public class SeekbarCheckbox extends TableLayout {
private SeekBar _Seekbar;
private CheckBox _CheckBox;
private TableRow _tr;

public SeekbarCheckbox(Context context, int max) {
    super(context);

     _tr = new TableRow(context);

     Button bt1 = new Button(context);
     bt1.setText("-");
     _tr.addView(bt1);

     _Seekbar = new SeekBar(context);
     _Seekbar.setMax(max);
     _tr.addView(_Seekbar);

     Button bt2 = new Button(context);
     bt2.setText("+");
     _tr.addView(bt2);


     this.addView(_tr, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

}
```

}

The thing is, when I use this control at the application I get the SeekBar with a useless width. I share an image to see the result.

I can't post an image, so I share a link.
http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/6756/controlk.png

Comment: Hi can you please let me know where and how exactly you are using this customlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to find the solution of the your problem. If you set weight as 1 on seekbar then it will acquire all space accept the minimum space required for buttons.
For me this code is working fine.

```
public class SeekbarCheckbox extends TableLayout {
    private SeekBar _Seekbar;
    private CheckBox _CheckBox;
    private TableRow _tr;

    public SeekbarCheckbox(Context context, int max) {
        super(context);

         _tr = new TableRow(context);

         Button bt1 = new Button(context);
         bt1.setText("-");
         _tr.addView(bt1);

         _Seekbar = new SeekBar(context);
         _Seekbar.setMax(max);
         TableRow.LayoutParams ob = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                              1);
         _tr.addView(_Seekbar, ob);

         Button bt2 = new Button(context);
         bt2.setText("+");
         _tr.addView(bt2);

         _tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
         this.addView(_tr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting weight value for the views should do the trick.

For Buttons :

```
setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f));
```

Seekbar:

```
setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 10f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your layout code like below

```
    public SeekBarcheckbox(Context context, int max) {
    super(context);

     _tr = new TableRow(context);
     _tr.setWeightSum(10f);
     Button bt1 = new Button(context);
     bt1.setText("-");
     TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams=new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,2f);
     _tr.addView(bt1, layoutParams);
     _Seekbar = new SeekBar(context);
     _Seekbar.setMax(max);
   TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams1=new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,7f);
     _tr.addView(_Seekbar,layoutParams1);
     Button bt2 = new Button(context);
     bt2.setText("+");
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
     _tr.addView(bt2,layoutParams3);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     this.addView(_tr,layoutParams2);

}
```

and i used within activity the below code

```
    seekBarcheckbox=new SeekBarcheckbox(this, 100);
    setContentView(seekBarcheckbox);
```

its working for me...